# Maneira mais rápida de contar quantos registos tenho numa tabela MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Como o título diz queria saber qual é maneira mais rápida de contar registos de uma tabela com milhares de registos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a forma mais fácil é usando o COUNT, Eu o utilizo diariamente e nuca tive problemas e uso em bases grandes.

A função COUNT (*) retorna o número de registros em uma tabela:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;
```

O COUNT (DISTINCT column_name) devolve o número de valores distintos da coluna especificada:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Como consigo colocar o quantidade de registos que retorna dentro de uma variavel php?

Comment: @xdam98 ai ja é uma outra pergunta, abra Ela separada que virão muitas respostas boas.

Comment: ainda mais rapido seria: SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_name; pois o banco irá interpretar a linha inteira como valor 1... usando * o banco vê todos os valores da linha

Answer (score 1):

Você poderá utilizar a função count() para fazer isso.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela
```

e você também poderá fazer isso utilizando filtros de suas tabelas para trazer apenas o que te interessa:

```
SELECT coluna1, coluna2, COUNT(*) FROM tabela
WHERE coluna1 = 'dado' OR coluna2 = 'dado'
GROUP BY coluna1, coluna2;
```